# How can siunitx be used with mathematics environment notation?

Tags: siunitx, units, mathematics

How can mathematics environment notation be used with units provided by siunitx? Let's way I want to have some code like the following:

```
\SI{10^{-28}}{m^{2}}
```

Is it possible to use this mathematics style of notation with siunitx (not the siunitx `10e-28` type of notation)? Is the following a valid alternative?

```
${10^{-28}}$\,\si{m^{2}}
```

How could a mathematics style equation be used with siunitx, something like the following?

```
${a^{b}}$\,\si{m^{2}}
```

Comment: @JosephWright Hey, thanks for the suggestion. It's a step in the right direction, but when I use code like `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{a^{b}}{m^{2}}`, I get the mathematics showing in Roman lettering rather than the mathematics lettering. Do you know how to get the mathematics showing correctly? The best I've got remains the `${a^{b}}$\,\si{m^{2}}` approach.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe there is a misunderstanding going on here? Could it be what you want is simply for the format output to be in the format base^exp? Most likely 10^x? It just seems too strange that you'd want to attach units to arbitrary formulas. Also you forgot to include the second option of Joseph's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can turn off the number parse and the 'font control' with something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI[parse-numbers = false, number-math-rm = \ensuremath]{a^{b}}{\metre}

\end{document}
```

However, I wonder about the meaning here: it's hard for me to see how you can have a physical quantity expressed in that form!

Comment: The permeability of free space might be a good example. $\mu_0 = 4\pi\times10^{-7}\,\mathrm{H}\,\mathrm{m}^{-1}$

Comment: Is it recommended/usual to use `siunitx` *ouside* math mode? I always thought all `siunitx` commands should be wrapped inside `\(\)`.

Answer (score 1):

With the default configuration, just type `\SI{e-28}{m^2}`:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. What I'm looking to do is specifically to use the standard LaTeX mathematics environment notation with siunitx; that is, I want to use the text `10^{-28}` rather than the text `e-28`. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Unless you hack `siunitx`, this is not possible. Is there any reason for you to do so? Siunitx is here to avoid the hassle of having to type $10^{-28}\,\mathrm{m}^2$, and it does so in maths mode.